# [Python ]How can I write a program which is asking for multiple numbers and adding them together until there is a 0?

Tags: python

My task is:
Create a program which is asking for multiple integers and sums them up. Indicate the end of the integers with 0!

This should be done with "while" loop.

My logic:
So basically the numbers should only be added together before the 0, but not the numbers after the 0. Am I correct?

I'm relatively new in python.

Can anyone help my out?

This is what I was trying:

```
a = [int(a) for a in input("Numbers: ").split()]
print(a)
add=0
while a != 0:
    add = add+a    
print(add)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Daweed Updated my original question with the code which I was trying to write.

Comment: make yourself clear in the question. I just can not understand what you actually want to do with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `for` loop instead with `break` condition:

```
for elt in a:
    if elt == 0:
        break
    add = add + elt
print(add)
```

The below code with `while` implies that the condition will always be true since you are not iterating the elements of the list:

```
while a != 0:
    add = add+a # also adding int (add) with list (a) is not what you need
```

If you need to work with `while`, you need to iterate over the elements which you can do with index-based access as:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a) and a[i] != 0:
    add = add + a[i]
    i = i + 1
    
print(add)
```